# Extremely slow distinct query on indexed column

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, distinct

In a Postgres database, I am querying distinct values of `MY_DATE` in a large table with 300 million rows. There are about 400 of them and the column `MY_DATE` is indexed.

```
Select distinct  MY_DATE from MY_TABLE;
```

The query runs for **22 min**.

The same query on my Oracle DB with the exact same data-set and the same index definition runs 11 seconds.

The query plan shows that the query is using the index:

```
EXPLAIN Select distinct  MY_DATE from MY_TABLE LIMIT 200;
```

gives:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.57..7171644.14 rows=200 width=8)
  ->  Unique  (cost=0.57..15419034.24 rows=430 width=8)
        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_obsdate on my_table  (cost=0.57..14672064.14 rows=298788038 width=8)
```

When I limit the results, the query can become much faster. Ee.g.

```
Select distinct  MY_DATE from MY_TABLE LIMIT 5;
```

runs in sub-seconds.

but:

```
Select distinct  MY_DATE from MY_TABLE LIMIT 50;
```

already takes minutes. Time seems to increase exponentially with the `LIMIT` clause.

I expect the Postgres query to run in seconds, as my OracleDB does.
20 minutes for an index scan - even for a large table - seems way off the mark.

Any suggestions what causes the issue and what I can do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Postgres has index-only scans. And it does not need row locks for a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> distinct values ... 300 million rows ... about 400 of them ... column ... indexed.

There are *much* faster techniques for this. Emulating a [loose index scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) (a.k.a. skip scan), and assuming `my_date`  is defined `NOT NULL` (or we can ignore NULL values):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT min(my_date) AS my_date
   FROM   my_table

   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT my_date
           FROM   my_table 
           WHERE  my_date > cte.my_date
           ORDER  BY my_date
           LIMIT  1)
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  my_date IS NOT NULL
   )
TABLE  cte;
```

Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Using the index you mentioned it should finish in **milliseconds**.

> Oracle DB ... 11 seconds.

Because Oracle has native index skip scans and Postgres does not. There are [ongoing efforts](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/707b6f68-16fa-7aa7-96e5-eeb4865e6a30@redhat.com) to implement similar functionality in Postgres 12.

Currently (Postgres 11), while the index is used to good effect, even in an index-only scan, Postgres cannot skip ahead and has to read index tuples in sequence. Without `LIMIT`, the complete index has to be scanned. Hence we see in your `EXPLAIN` output:

> ```
> Index Only Scan ... rows=298788038
> ```

The suggested new query achieves the same with reading 400 index tuples (one per distinct value). *Big* difference.

With `LIMIT` (and no `ORDER BY`!)  like you tested, Postgres stops as soon as enough rows are retrieved. Increasing the limit has a ***linear*** effect. But if the number of rows per distinct value can vary, so does the added cost.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the good explanation. Unfortunately your query also seems to run slow: CTE Scan on cte  (cost=1061000068.83..1061000070.85 rows=101 width=8)
  CTE cte
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=7872574.05..1061000068.83 rows=101 width=8)
          ->  WorkTable Scan on cte cte_1  (cost=0.00..105312749.28 rows=10 width=8)
          ->  Finalize Aggregate  (cost=7872574.05..7872574.06 rows=1 width=8)
                Filter: (observation_date IS NOT NULL)
                ->  Gather  (cost=7872573.83..7872574.04 rows=2 width=8)

Comment: Workers Planned: 2
                      ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=7871573.83..7871573.84 rows=1 width=8)
                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on observations_2018feed_prod  (cost=0.00..7562306.27 rows=123707027 width=8)

Comment: is this suggesting it will do a parallel scan on 123 million rows?

Comment: @tomsnizer: that shouldn't be. you shouldn't see a seq scan. if you provide postgres version, table and index definition (`CREATE ... ` scripts) *in the question*, I may able to find why ...

Comment: I dropped the index and recreated the index. And now your query does run in 45ms! Thank you so much.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter can you provide an example of using this recursive CTE method with multiple columns from the table? If I have, say, four columns that are not null that I want to select distinct on, how do I do that with a recursive CTE?

Comment: @jkeys: Can be implemented efficiently. I suggest you start a new *question*  for your question.